# Differentiating an integral with FTC

Tags: real-analysis

**Question:** How to differentiate function $x\rightarrow$$\int^x_0 f(x-t)g(t)dt$?

**My solution attempt:** $$\int^x_0 f(x-t)g(t)dt=\left[f(x-t)G(t) \right]^x_0-\int^x_0 f'(x-t)\cdot(-1)\cdot G(t)dt=f(0)G(x)-f(x)G(0)+\int^x_0f'(x-t)G(t)dt$$

If I differentiate it, I get: $$\frac{d}{dt}\int^x_0f(x-t)g(t)dt=0\cdot G(x)+f(0)g(x)-f'(x)G(0)-f(x)\cdot 0 + \frac{d}{dt}\int^x_0f'(x-t)G(t)dt =$$ $$=\frac{d}{dt}\int^x_0f'(x-t)G(t)dt+f(0)g(x)-f'(x)G(0)$$

I checked the solution with WolframAlpha and it seems I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly when you differentiate the function $x \mapsto \int_{0}^{x} f(x-t)g(t) dt$ you must **differentiate with respect to $x$, not $t$**. $t$ is just some dummy variable. It may help to think of it like this: let $F(x) = \int_{0}^{x} f(x-t)g(t) dt$, and compute $\frac{dF}{dx}$. Can you see how the FTC will apply?